# Better Java collection type for fast search element by any subsrting in its field

Tags: java, arrays, collections

May seems its a simple question, but i need help...
I have a collection of objects with some fields: `id`, `agreementNum` etc:
`List<Agreement> agreementEntities = new ArrayList<>();`
There are 40 000 items in it.

In the programm i need to find an element(s) by any substring of `agreementNum`. 
For example, i will find element by `12321` or `12321\ABC` subsrting in `agreementNum`.

What is the better type of collection to find object by substring of its field?

Comment: The data structure which would probably make the most sense here is actually a B-tree, which databases use to sort records based on the text of a given field.  But, I don't know offhand of any Java libraries which offer this functionality.

Comment: A Trie might be suitable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), but there's no JDK implementation

Comment: As another commenter has pointed out, tries are a possible solution to this. I have used [Aho-Corasick Tries](https://github.com/hankcs/AhoCorasickDoubleArrayTrie) before personally, but there are many libraries out there. Just search for the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: Also take a look at [PatriciaTrie from Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html), though I think that it only supports prefix search.